# Alternatives to deprecated Facebook Places Search API for Web

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to provide users of my app the search input where they can look for a place that will be later used to publish an online event to Facebook using the Official Events API - there is a requirement that an online event has place ID provided. I am using the JS SDK.

On August 3, 2020 Facebook has removed the [Places Search API for Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search/) in their API `v8.0` (as for today it's still available in versions prior to `v8.0` but I'm not sure how long it will be available, I also wanted to upgrade the API version I'm using in the app). I was trying to find any alternatives to the deprecated endpoint but couldn't find any.

Does anyone know if there are any other options to get the place ID for a given search query?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like I could use [Pages Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching) endpoint with `fields=id,name,location` and just look for pages that have the location set. However this endpoint needs [Page Public Metadata Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#page-public-metadata-access) permission when not using user access tokens.

Comment: I'm tackling the same problem and tried your approach here. When I pass the ID of a page with location set as the place ID for a post, I get an error that I haven't specified a valid place. Is there a different ID value that should be supplied as the place ID?

Comment: It looks like FB has changed something and haven't documented the change (or I just couldn't find it) - I'm having the same issue for some time now and haven't resolved it yet... But for some period of time it was working with the Pages Search endpoint